# Looking for something like onlive desktop with Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: remote-desktop

I'm trying to see if there is an online application that would allow me to 'rent' a PC remotely. In much the same way as you could remote connect to a server within Windows (via Remote Connection), I'd like to be able to remote into a PC that is off-site, where the data stays secure, and where I could install new applications.

Yes, this is pretty much asking if there is something that already exists that would be a remote connection to a Windows PC. I'm on a Mac and am a developer, but Bootcamp means I have to keep switching machines, and the VM's/Parallels are just not fast enough. I don't want to be running two machines for the different OS's if I can.

Any advice or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Third-party remote data = no guarantee of security.

Comment: I'm not after a guarantee. I use dropbox, google mail and github, I know there's no guarantee of security, but at least enough that I could trust it in the same way as I do dropbox.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use Amazon Web Services EC2. It's a cloud service where you can spin up instances of whatever OS you need. I often use a Windows Server VM on AWS so I can do Windows stuff on my Mac when I'm on the road. I believe micro Windows instances are now available under AWS's free tier (double-check me though) so you could try it out with no risk. Even if you do have to pay, it's like 10 bucks/month to run a Windows server nonstop with moderate bandwidth usage.